# Autofill multiple fields with similar data

Tags: entities, nodes, ajax

I would like to have field B auto filled while field A is being filled.

For example, for content type **account**, I have fields *username*, *user email*. While I enter `example` in *username*, *user email* is supposed to auto populate itself as `example@gmail.com`

Thanks

Comment: This could all be accomplished with javascript and isn't really a Drupal specific question.

Comment: but where do I add the javascript for that?

Comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7